# Unable to download previously uploaded .apk file from TestFairy

Tags: android, testfairy

I am using TestFairy for uploading .apk file for testing. Problem is I am unable to download previously uploaded .apk files from older links infact from older links only latest .apk version file is getting downloaded. And version number is showing same for all the .apk file which ever I have uploaded till now. And while uploading .apk file through Testfairy, it says
"TestFairy SDK not integrated in build, no recordings will be performed."

Answer (score 0):

How are you downloading this APK?

- If you are using email invites, then the link should work fine with no problems.
- If you are using the download page, it might be that you have your download page set to download the auto-update build. Please go to the latest version, and in Build Settings, check the "Upgrade to this build" checkbox.
- Webhooks, Testers App for Android and push notifications, you get invited to a specific version, so I don't believe this is the case.

About missing SDK

- TestFairy also has an Insights SDK, this SDK will record videos when users are running your app on their devices. It will also handle crashes and it's very recommended you try the SDK to see its benefits. You can install the SDK by simply adding a couple of lines to your Android Gradle and a single line of code. Here is the documentation: https://docs.testfairy.com/Android/Integrating_Android_SDK.html

Comment: Thanks for you Answer, Whenever I upload .apk file through TestFairy, I receive an email and by clicking - "In order to download and install the app, please click here" link. I try to download the .apk. file. I am getting same .apk ( Latest .apk file) from all the previously uploaded .apk files.

Comment: Can you please send such email to TestFairy support? they will take a look at that specific case.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have sent an email regarding this. Hope I find a solution from their team.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for the problem from TestFairy team. By changing the versionName every time in 'build.gradle'-->'defaultConfig' solved my problem.